# bsdoc function removed from ReporteRs package, how to create html for mail now?

Tags: r

I used to send mail by below code using reporters function.
After updating of this package, bsdoc / addparagraph not working now.
As i check [update remarks](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/packages/ReporteRs/NEWS) of this package, there was mentioned that these are removed now.

What is the right code for me?

```
date2 <- paste("Mail subject)
setwd("/filepath/")

mydoc = bsdoc( title = 'my document')
options( "ReporteRs-fontsize" = 8 )
mydoc = addParagraph(mydoc, value = "Hi All, \n\nPlease check the summary")
MyFTable = FlexTable( data = first6, add.rownames = FALSE, header.cell.props = cellProperties( background.color = "#FAEBD7" ), header.par.props = parProperties(text.align = "center" ))
MyFTable = setColumnsColors( MyFTable, j=1, colors = '#F0F8FF' )
MyFTable[ , ] = parProperties( text.align = 'center')
mydoc = addFlexTable( mydoc, MyFTable )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = "op2.html" )
```

Comment: Install an old version of the package and continue using it as before?

Comment: Yes, using this way, but asking the question for any way to use this in the updated package, does developer replace this with another way or?

Comment: Did you read the notes? Don't know anything about this, but doesn't it say `bsdoc is deprecated. The API has no more reason to be maintained as rmarkdown and many other solutions are offering better.`